# Negation Function for style files

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to read about `.bst` files from [Tame the Beast](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). On page 38, there is this example for a negation function:

```
FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
```

I don't understand what `#0` and `#1` are. Also, in the definition of `if` on page 33, it requires three arguments `I F1 F2`, but in the code why are there only two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{#0}` and `{#1}` are equivalent to `F1` and `F2`. And `I` is the top of the stack before you call `not` (`I` is the value to negate). If `I` is true, `if$` executes `F1` (here #0, i.e. *false*). If `I` is false, `if$` executes `F2` (here #1, i.e. *true*).

Comment: I see, thanks Paul! Are `#0` and `#1` universal constants in `.bst`? And are there `#2`, `#3`, `#4`, ...? (I'm asking because I don't see it mentioned anywhere in Tame the Beast.)

Comment: @MikaH.: `#` is the prefix for integers (see note 36 p. 32).